# QComboBox: item does not appear in the LineEdit field when selected

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qabstractitemmodel, qstandarditemmodel

I have a small program, I try to create my personal combo box with the popup having multiple columns like this:

[image]

Below is the constructor of my combo box.

**MyComboBox.h**

```
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QTreeView>
#include "CompleterData.h"

class MyComboFor : public QComboBox
{      
public:
  MyComboBox( QWidget *p_parent = nullptr );
  CompleterData createTestData();

private:
  QTreeView *m_view = nullptr;
  CompleterSourceModel *m_sourceModel = nullptr;
};
```

**MyComboBox.cpp**

```
MyComboBox::MyComboBox( QWidget *p_parent ) : QComboBox( p_parent )
{
  setEditable( true );
  m_view = new QTreeView();
  m_sourceModel = new CompleterSourceModel( this );
  m_sourceModel->setCompleterData( createTestData() );      
  setModel( m_sourceModel );
  setCurrentText( "" );
  setView( m_view );
}

CompleterData MyComboBox::createTestData()
{
  CompleterData data;
  data.addData( CompleterDataRow( CompleterDataRow::Type::Header, { { "Last Used", {} } } ) );
  data.addData( CompleterDataRow( CompleterDataRow::Type::LastUsed, { { "PwC", {}}, {"Partner want Cash", {}} } ) );
  data.addData( CompleterDataRow( CompleterDataRow::Type::LastUsed, { { "CLASS", {}}, {"Come late and start sleeping", {}} } ) );
  data.addData( CompleterDataRow( CompleterDataRow::Type::LastUsed, { { "DIET", {}}, {"Do I eat today?", {}} } ) );
  data.addData( CompleterDataRow( CompleterDataRow::Type::SecondHeader, { { "Lorem Ipsum", {} } } ) );
  data.addData( CompleterDataRow( CompleterDataRow::Type::Data, { { "FBI", {} }, { "Female Body Inspector", {} } } ) );
  data.addData( CompleterDataRow( CompleterDataRow::Type::Data, { { "PIG", {} }, { "Pretty Insensitive Guy", {} } } ) );
  data.addData( CompleterDataRow( CompleterDataRow::Type::Data, { { "SMILE", {} }, { "Showing Miracle In Little Effort", {} } } ) );
  data.addData( CompleterDataRow( CompleterDataRow::Type::Data, { { "TEAM", {} }, { "Together Everyone Achieves More", {} } } ) );
  data.addData( CompleterDataRow( CompleterDataRow::Type::Header, { { "Some Countries", {} } } ) );
  data.addData( CompleterDataRow( CompleterDataRow::Type::SecondHeader, { { "Some Cities", {} } } ) );
  data.setTitle( "Proposal List" );
  data.setHeaders( { "Abbreviation", "Meaning" } );
  return data;
}
```

My data for the popup has vector structure. In this vector, each element is one row of the popup. Each row consists of its type and the texts to be shown. The texts are wrapped in a QPair (the requirement is so), and all the pairs are wrapped in a QList.

**CompleterData.h**

```
#include <QList>
#include <QPair>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QVector>

class CompleterDataRow
{
public:
  enum class Type
  {
     Header,
     SecondHeader,
     Data,
     LastUsed         
  };
  CompleterDataRow() = default;
  CompleterDataRow( const CompleterDataRow::Type p_rowType, const QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>> &p_rowData );
  void setType( const CompleterDataRow::Type p_type );
  CompleterDataRow::Type type() const;
  QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>> rowData() const;
  void setRowData( const QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>> &p_rowData );

private:
  QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>> m_rowData;
  Type m_type;
};

class CompleterData
{
public:
  CompleterData() = default;
  QVector<CompleterDataRow> data() const;
  void setData( const QVector<CompleterDataRow> &p_data );
  void addData( const CompleterDataRow &p_rowData );
  void removeData( int p_row );
  void setHeaders( const QStringList &p_headers );
  void setTitle( const QString &p_label );
  const QStringList &headers() const;
  const QString &title() const;

private:
  QVector<CompleterDataRow> m_completerData;
  QString m_title;
  QStringList m_headers;
};
```

**CompleterData.cpp**

```
#include "CompleterData.h"

CompleterDataRow::CompleterDataRow( const CompleterDataRow::Type p_rowType, const QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>> &p_rowData )
{
  m_type = p_rowType;
  m_rowData = p_rowData;
}

QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>> CompleterDataRow::rowData() const
{
  return m_rowData;
}

void CompleterDataRow::setRowData( const QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>> &p_rowData )
{
  m_rowData = p_rowData;
}

CompleterDataRow::Type CompleterDataRow::type() const
{
  return m_type;
}

void CompleterDataRow::setType( const Type p_type )
{
  m_type = p_type;
}

QVector<CompleterDataRow> CompleterData::data() const
{
  return m_completerData;
}

void CompleterData::addData( const CompleterDataRow &p_rowData )
{
  m_completerData.append( p_rowData );
}

void CompleterData::removeData( int p_row )
{
  m_completerData.remove( p_row );
}

void CompleterData::setData( const QVector<CompleterDataRow> &p_data )
{
  m_completerData = p_data;
}

void CompleterData::setTitle( const QString &p_title )
{
  m_title = p_title;
}

const QString &CompleterData::title() const
{
  return m_title;
}

void CompleterData::setHeaders( const QStringList &p_headers )
{
  m_headers = p_headers;
}

const QStringList &CompleterData::headers() const
{
  return m_headers;
}
```

And I use QStandardItemModel in this case. I only override some functions of QAbstractItemModel as below.

**CompleterSourceModel.h**

```
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include "CompleterData.h"

class CompleterSourceModel : public QStandardItemModel
{
public:
  CompleterSourceModel( QObject *p_parent = nullptr );
  CompleterSourceModel( const CompleterData &p_completerData, QObject *p_parent = nullptr );
  QVariant data( const QModelIndex &p_index, int p_role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const override;
  QVariant headerData( int p_section, Qt::Orientation p_orientation, int p_role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const override;
  Qt::ItemFlags flags( const QModelIndex &index ) const override;
  int rowCount( const QModelIndex &p_parent = QModelIndex() ) const override;
  int columnCount( const QModelIndex &p_parent = QModelIndex() ) const override;
  void setCompleterData( const CompleterData &p_completerData );

private:
  CompleterData m_completerData;
};
```

**CompleterSourceModel.cpp**

```
#include "CompleterSourceModel.h"

CompleterSourceModel::CompleterSourceModel( QObject *p_parent ) : QStandardItemModel( p_parent )
{
}

QVariant CompleterSourceModel::data( const QModelIndex &p_index, int p_role ) const
{
  if ( p_role == Qt::UserRole ) {
     if ( m_completerData.data().size() > p_index.row() ) {
        return QVariant( static_cast<int>( m_completerData.data().at( p_index.row() ).type() ) );
     }
  }
  else if ( p_role == Qt::DisplayRole ) {
     QList<QPair<QString, QVariant>> rowContent = m_completerData.data().at( p_index.row() ).rowData();
     CompleterDataRow::Type type = m_completerData.data().at( p_index.row() ).type();
     if ( type == CompleterDataRow::Type::Header || type == CompleterDataRow::Type::SecondHeader ) {
        if ( p_index.column() == 0 ) {
           return rowContent.first().first;
        }
     }
     else {
        if ( rowContent.size() > p_index.column() ) {
           return rowContent.at( p_index.column() ).first;
        }
     }
  }

  return {};
}

QVariant CompleterSourceModel::headerData( int p_section, Qt::Orientation p_orientation, int p_role ) const
{
  if ( p_role == Qt::DisplayRole && p_orientation == Qt::Horizontal ) {
     if ( m_completerData.headers().size() > p_section ) {
        return m_completerData.headers().at( p_section );
     }
  }

  return {};
}

Qt::ItemFlags CompleterSourceModel::flags( const QModelIndex &p_index ) const
{
  if ( !p_index.isValid() ) {
     return Qt::NoItemFlags;
  }

  CompleterDataRow::Type type = m_completerData.data().at( p_index.row() ).type();
  if ( type == CompleterDataRow::Type::Data || type == CompleterDataRow::Type::LastUsed ) {
     return Qt::ItemIsSelectable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
  }
  return Qt::NoItemFlags;
}

int CompleterSourceModel::rowCount( const QModelIndex &p_parent ) const
{
  Q_UNUSED( p_parent );
  return m_completerData.data().size();
}

int CompleterSourceModel::columnCount( const QModelIndex &p_parent ) const
{
  Q_UNUSED( p_parent );
  return m_completerData.headers().size() + 1;
}

void CompleterSourceModel::setCompleterData( const CompleterData &p_completerData )
{
  m_completerData = p_completerData;
  setColumnCount( m_completerData.headers().size() + 1 );
  setRowCount( m_completerData.data().size() );
  for ( int row = 0; row < m_completerData.data().size(); row++ ) {
     if ( m_completerData.data().at( row ).type() == CompleterDataRow::Type::Header || m_completerData.data().at( row ).type() == CompleterDataRow::Type::SecondHeader ) {
        QString text = m_completerData.data().at( row ).rowData().at( 0 ).first;
        setData( index( row, 0 ), m_completerData.data().at( row ).rowData().at( 0 ).first );
     }
     else {
        for ( int col = 0; col < m_completerData.headers().size(); col++ ) {    
           QString text = m_completerData.data().at( row ).rowData().at( col ).first;
           setData( index( row, col ), m_completerData.data().at( row ).rowData().at( col ).first );
        }
     }
  }
}
```

With this work, the data is already shown as you can see above. But when I click onto 1 line of the list (the marked line above), the word "TEAM" is not written into the LineEdit field. I don't know why???

If I write in the constructor of my combo box like this:

```
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel( this );
model->setColumnCount( 1 );
model->setRowCount( 5 );
model->setData( model->index( 0, 0 ), "some data0" );
model->setData( model->index( 1, 0 ), "some data1" );
model->setData( model->index( 2, 0 ), "some data2" );
model->setData( model->index( 3, 0 ), "some data3" );
model->setData( model->index( 4, 0 ), "some data4" );
setModel( model );
```

then everything works well. So I guess my model has problem, but I don't know where exactly, is that because I do not override all the functions of QAbstractItemModel ? Please help me!

Comment: @eyllanesc: sorry, I wanted to use github but I did not use it before :( so I put my code here sothat you guys can see my data.

Comment: But the code you have provided is incomplete

Comment: @eyllanesc: Sorry, I have added more details to the code :). Pls help me!

Comment: If you are using QStandardItemModel it is not necessary, and in case you should not implement the data, rowCount and columnCount methods, if you remove those methods then your logic will work

Comment: @eyllanesc: thank you very much. So I should not also implement `headerData()` any more and use `setHeaderData()` in my function `void CompleterSourceModel::setCompleterData( const CompleterData &p_completerData )` right?

Comment: Yes, QStandardItemModel already has methods like the one you point out that do the job you point out